# Getting Null pointer Exception while writing into Excel file

Tags: nullpointerexception, automated-tests

Getting a `Null Pointer Exception` while writing into Excel file:

```
public static void setCellData(String Result,  int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {

        try{

                Rw  = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum);

                Cell = Rw.getCell(ColNum, null);

                if (Cell == null) {

                    Cell = Rw.createCell(ColNum);

                    Cell.setCellValue(Result);

                    } else {

                        Cell.setCellValue(Result);

                    }
           FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Path_TestData + File_TestData);

                    ExcelWBook.write(fileOut);

                    fileOut.flush();

                    fileOut.close();

                    }catch(Exception e){

                        throw (e);

                }
```

And passing parameters from another class

```
File.setCellData("Pass", 2, 2);
```

This is throwing an exception error as `Null Pointer Exception`.
I have already used `createRow()` method instead of the `getRow()` to avoid null value & my excel has data but still getting an error.

Can anyone please help to resolve this error?

Comment: Can you share the exact error message and the steps you've done to find the error?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code below and try it.
I hope it will help you.

```js
public static void setCellData(String Result,  int RowNum, int ColNum) throws Exception {

        try{
   
     //Blank workbook
     XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

     //Create a blank sheet
     XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");
     XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet = sheet;
     XSSFCell Cell;
     XSSFRow Row;
     Row  = ExcelWSheet.createRow(RowNum);

     Cell = Row.getCell(ColNum, org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

     if (Cell == null) {

      Cell = Row.createCell(ColNum);

      Cell.setCellValue(Result);

      } else {

       Cell.setCellValue(Result);

      }

     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Done.xlsx"));
     workbook.write(out);
     out.close();
     System.out.println("sreeraj done the code");

                    }catch(Exception e){

                        throw (e);

                }
```

Comment: Thank you Sreeraj for help. You are creating new sheet but i am using single sheet from where data is being fetched & written. Can you please help me in my code?